# Ruby on Rails: Removing a dependency while installing a gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, twitter-bootstrap

I'm attempting to gem install twitter-bootstrap-rails on my windows machine.  This gem has a dependency on therubyracer, which is not yet compatible with Windows.  I found this:

[therubyracer gem on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6356450/therubyracer-gem-on-windows)

Which tells me I should just be able to lean on JScript.  Though I don't know how to tell the gem install to ignore dependencies.  I've tried to force install with:

```
    gem install -f twitter-bootstrap-rails --platform ruby
```

To no avail.  Does anyone how I can say something like "gem install twitter-bootstrap-rails [but ignore that dependency on therubyracer]"?

Comment: I think the `-f` should be after the gem name `twitter-bootstrap-rails`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [this doc](http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/10#page33), there's the options

```
-f, --[no-]force            Force gem to install, bypassing dependency checks
```

and

```
--ignore-dependencies        Do not install any required dependent gems
```

Comment: Thanks Baldrick, not sure how I missed that.  Cheers

Comment: Hey guys, I'm running into the same problem. How do I specify these options in my gemfile so that my bundle install works correctly?

Comment: Archived docs link: http://web.archive.org/web/20080201092913/http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/10

Answer (score 7):

If your goal is to get the rails twitter boostrap working on Windows, there is a version of this that uses static CSS, avoiding the fixed dependency on therubyracer.  This will install on Windows.  You won't have the Less functionality, but it does work in Windows.  Try this in your Gemfile:

```
gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails', :git => "git://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails.git", :branch => "static"
```

Comment: Don't forget, if you use the static branch, you have to add the compiled bootstrap.css file to your asset pipeline by adding the following line to your application.css file:

    /*
     *= require bootstrap
    */

[https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails/blob/static/README.md](https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails/blob/static/README.md)