# When I do "bundle update", I get an error from a gem not in my gemfile. How do I ignore this dependency?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working with a project that uses twitter-bootstrap-rails.  This project was built on a Linux box, and used therubyracer as a javascript runtime.  I've been running into issues because therubyracer doesn't seem to get along with Windows.

[therubyracer gem on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6356450/therubyracer-gem-on-windows)

Right now I'm trying to "bundle update"; "therubyracer" is choking things up.

I think I should be able to lean on JScript.  How do I tell bundler to ignore this, without digging into each gem and manually removing its dependency on therubyracer?  It seems like bootstrap, or at least twitter-bootstrap-rails, depends on therubyracer.

Edit: I've followed the instructions in that thread, and I keep getting the following (after bundle install development):

```
   Installing railties (3.2.0)
Installing coffee-rails (3.2.2)
Installing libv8 (3.3.10.4) with native extensions
Installing therubyracer (0.9.10) with native extensions
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        C:/Ruby/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make
generating v8-i386-mingw32.def
compiling rr.cpp
cc1plus.exe: warning: command line option "-Wdeclaration-after-statement" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
cc1plus.exe: warning: command line option "-Wimplicit-function-declaration" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
rr.cpp: In function 'VALUE rr_define_finalizer(VALUE, void*, VALUE)':
rr.cpp:48:1: warning: no return statement in function returning non-void
In file included from rr.cpp:3:0:
v8_handle.h: In function 'v8::Persistent<T>& rr_v8_handle(VALUE) [with T = v8::Value, VALUE = long unsigned int]':
rr.cpp:159:37:   instantiated from here
v8_handle.h:43:71: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules
g++.exe: unrecognized option '-rdynamic'
compiling v8.cpp
cc1plus.exe: warning: command line option "-Wdeclaration-after-statement" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
cc1plus.exe: warning: command line option "-Wimplicit-function-declaration" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
g++.exe: unrecognized option '-rdynamic'
compiling v8_array.cpp
cc1plus.exe: warning: command line option "-Wdeclaration-after-statement" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
cc1plus.exe: warning: command line option "-Wimplicit-function-declaration" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
In file included from v8_array.cpp:1:0:
v8_handle.h: In function 'v8::Persistent<T>& rr_v8_handle(VALUE) [with T = v8::Array, VALUE = long unsigned int]':
v8_array.cpp:13:36:   instantiated from here
v8_handle.h:43:71: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules
g++.exe: unrecognized option '-rdynamic'
compiling v8_callbacks.cpp
cc1plus.exe: warning: command line option "-Wdeclaration-after-statement" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
cc1plus.exe: warning: command line option "-Wimplicit-function-declaration" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
g++.exe: unrecognized option '-rdynamic'
compiling v8_context.cpp
cc1plus.exe: warning: command line option "-Wdeclaration-after-statement" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
cc1plus.exe: warning: command line option "-Wimplicit-function-declaration" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
In file included from v8_context.cpp:2:0:
v8_handle.h: In function 'v8::Persistent<T>& rr_v8_handle(VALUE) [with T = v8::Context, VALUE = long unsigned int]':
v8_context.cpp:15:39:   instantiated from here
v8_handle.h:43:71: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules
v8_handle.h: In function 'v8::Persistent<T>& rr_v8_handle(VALUE) [with T = v8::ObjectTemplate, VALUE = long unsigned int]':
v8_context.cpp:22:143:   instantiated from here
v8_handle.h:43:71: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules
v8_handle.h: In function 'v8::Persistent<T>& rr_v8_handle(VALUE) [with T = v8::Value, VALUE = long unsigned int]':
v8_context.cpp:23:110:   instantiated from here
v8_handle.h:43:71: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules
g++.exe: unrecognized option '-rdynamic'
compiling v8_date.cpp
cc1plus.exe: warning: command line option "-Wdeclaration-after-statement" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
cc1plus.exe: warning: command line option "-Wimplicit-function-declaration" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
In file included from v8_date.cpp:4:0:
v8_handle.h: In function 'v8::Persistent<T>& rr_v8_handle(VALUE) [with T = v8::Date, VALUE = long unsigned int]':
v8_date.cpp:21:52:   instantiated from here
v8_handle.h:43:71: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules
g++.exe: unrecognized option '-rdynamic'
compiling v8_debug.cpp
cc1plus.exe: warning: command line option "-Wdeclaration-after-statement" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
cc1plus.exe: warning: command line option "-Wimplicit-function-declaration" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
g++.exe: unrecognized option '-rdynamic'
compiling v8_exception.cpp
cc1plus.exe: warning: command line option "-Wdeclaration-after-statement" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
cc1plus.exe: warning: command line option "-Wimplicit-function-declaration" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
In file included from v8_exception.cpp:3:0:
v8_handle.h: In function 'v8::Persistent<T>& rr_v8_handle(VALUE) [with T = v8::StackTrace, VALUE = long unsigned int]':
v8_exception.cpp:48:44:   instantiated from here
v8_handle.h:43:71: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules
v8_handle.h: In function 'v8::Persistent<T>& rr_v8_handle(VALUE) [with T = v8::StackFrame, VALUE = long unsigned int]':
v8_exception.cpp:68:43:   instantiated from here
v8_handle.h:43:71: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules
v8_exception.cpp: At global scope:
v8_exception.cpp:10:24: warning: '<unnamed>::stack' defined but not used
g++.exe: unrecognized option '-rdynamic'
compiling v8_external.cpp
cc1plus.exe: warning: command line option "-Wdeclaration-after-statement" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
cc1plus.exe: warning: command line option "-Wimplicit-function-declaration" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
In file included from v8_external.cpp:4:0:
v8_handle.h: In function 'v8::Persistent<T>& rr_v8_handle(VALUE) [with T = v8::External, VALUE = long unsigned int]':
v8_external.cpp:51:60:   instantiated from here
v8_handle.h:43:71: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules
v8_external.cpp: At global scope:
v8_external.cpp:10:9: warning: '<unnamed>::references' defined but not used
g++.exe: unrecognized option '-rdynamic'
compiling v8_function.cpp
cc1plus.exe: warning: command line option "-Wdeclaration-after-statement" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
cc1plus.exe: warning: command line option "-Wimplicit-function-declaration" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
In file included from v8_function.cpp:5:0:
v8_handle.h: In function 'v8::Persistent<T>& rr_v8_handle(VALUE) [with T = v8::Function, VALUE = long unsigned int]':
v8_function.cpp:13:40:   instantiated from here
v8_handle.h:43:71: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules
v8_handle.h: In function 'v8::Persistent<T>& rr_v8_handle(VALUE) [with T = v8::Array, VALUE = long unsigned int]':
v8_function.cpp:23:55:   instantiated from here
v8_handle.h:43:71: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules
v8_handle.h: In function 'v8::Persistent<T>& rr_v8_handle(VALUE) [with T = v8::String, VALUE = long unsigned int]':
v8_function.cpp:49:51:   instantiated from here
v8_handle.h:43:71: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules
g++.exe: unrecognized option '-rdynamic'
compiling v8_handle.cpp
cc1plus.exe: warning: command line option "-Wdeclaration-after-statement" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
cc1plus.exe: warning: command line option "-Wimplicit-function-declaration" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
g++.exe: unrecognized option '-rdynamic'
compiling v8_locker.cpp
cc1plus.exe: warning: command line option "-Wdeclaration-after-statement" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
cc1plus.exe: warning: command line option "-Wimplicit-function-declaration" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
v8_locker.cpp: In function 'VALUE<unnamed>::Lock::Delete(VALUE)':
v8_locker.cpp:45:5: warning: no return statement in function returning non-void
v8_locker.cpp: In function 'VALUE<unnamed>::Unlock::Delete(VALUE)':
v8_locker.cpp:85:5: warning: no return statement in function returning non-void
g++.exe: unrecognized option '-rdynamic'
compiling v8_message.cpp
cc1plus.exe: warning: command line option "-Wdeclaration-after-statement" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
cc1plus.exe: warning: command line option "-Wimplicit-function-declaration" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
In file included from v8_message.cpp:2:0:
v8_handle.h: In function 'v8::Persistent<T>& rr_v8_handle(VALUE) [with T = v8::Message, VALUE = long unsigned int]':
v8_message.cpp:10:38:   instantiated from here
v8_handle.h:43:71: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules
g++.exe: unrecognized option '-rdynamic'
compiling v8_object.cpp
cc1plus.exe: warning: command line option "-Wdeclaration-after-statement" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
cc1plus.exe: warning: command line option "-Wimplicit-function-declaration" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
In file included from v8_object.cpp:1:0:
v8_handle.h: In function 'v8::Persistent<T>& rr_v8_handle(VALUE) [with T = v8::Object, VALUE = long unsigned int]':
v8_object.cpp:17:39:   instantiated from here
v8_handle.h:43:71: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules
g++.exe: unrecognized option '-rdynamic'
compiling v8_script.cpp
cc1plus.exe: warning: command line option "-Wdeclaration-after-statement" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
cc1plus.exe: warning: command line option "-Wimplicit-function-declaration" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
In file included from v8_script.cpp:2:0:
v8_handle.h: In function 'v8::Persistent<T>& rr_v8_handle(VALUE) [with T = v8::Script, VALUE = long unsigned int]':
v8_script.cpp:25:56:   instantiated from here
v8_handle.h:43:71: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules
g++.exe: unrecognized option '-rdynamic'
compiling v8_string.cpp
cc1plus.exe: warning: command line option "-Wdeclaration-after-statement" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
cc1plus.exe: warning: command line option "-Wimplicit-function-declaration" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
In file included from v8_string.cpp:3:0:
v8_handle.h: In function 'v8::Persistent<T>& rr_v8_handle(VALUE) [with T = v8::String, VALUE = long unsigned int]':
v8_string.cpp:13:38:   instantiated from here
v8_handle.h:43:71: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules
g++.exe: unrecognized option '-rdynamic'
compiling v8_template.cpp
cc1plus.exe: warning: command line option "-Wdeclaration-after-statement" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
cc1plus.exe: warning: command line option "-Wimplicit-function-declaration" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
In file included from v8_template.cpp:2:0:
v8_handle.h: In function 'v8::Persistent<T>& rr_v8_handle(VALUE) [with T = v8::Template, VALUE = long unsigned int]':
v8_template.cpp:42:39:   instantiated from here
v8_handle.h:43:71: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules
v8_handle.h: In function 'v8::Persistent<T>& rr_v8_handle(VALUE) [with T = v8::ObjectTemplate, VALUE = long unsigned int]':
v8_template.cpp:45:45:   instantiated from here
v8_handle.h:43:71: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules
v8_handle.h: In function 'v8::Persistent<T>& rr_v8_handle(VALUE) [with T = v8::FunctionTemplate, VALUE = long unsigned int]':
v8_template.cpp:48:47:   instantiated from here
v8_handle.h:43:71: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules
v8_handle.h: In function 'v8::Persistent<T>& rr_v8_handle(VALUE) [with T = v8::Data, VALUE = long unsigned int]':
v8_template.cpp:54:53:   instantiated from here
v8_handle.h:43:71: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules
g++.exe: unrecognized option '-rdynamic'
compiling v8_try_catch.cpp
cc1plus.exe: warning: command line option "-Wdeclaration-after-statement" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
cc1plus.exe: warning: command line option "-Wimplicit-function-declaration" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
g++.exe: unrecognized option '-rdynamic'
compiling v8_v8.cpp
cc1plus.exe: warning: command line option "-Wdeclaration-after-statement" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
cc1plus.exe: warning: command line option "-Wimplicit-function-declaration" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
g++.exe: unrecognized option '-rdynamic'
compiling v8_value.cpp
cc1plus.exe: warning: command line option "-Wdeclaration-after-statement" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
cc1plus.exe: warning: command line option "-Wimplicit-function-declaration" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
In file included from v8_value.cpp:1:0:
v8_handle.h: In function 'v8::Persistent<T>& rr_v8_handle(VALUE) [with T = v8::Value, VALUE = long unsigned int]':
v8_value.cpp:10:37:   instantiated from here
v8_handle.h:43:71: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules
g++.exe: unrecognized option '-rdynamic'
compiling v8_weakref.cpp
cc1plus.exe: warning: command line option "-Wdeclaration-after-statement" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
cc1plus.exe: warning: command line option "-Wimplicit-function-declaration" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
g++.exe: unrecognized option '-rdynamic'
linking shared-object v8.so
g++.exe: C:/inetpub/wwwroot/app/development/ruby/1.9.1/gems/libv8-3.3.10.4/lib/libv8/build/v8/libv8.a: No such file or directory
make: *** [v8.so] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in C:/inetpub/wwwroot/app/development/ruby/1.9.1/gems/therubyracer-0.9.10 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/inetpub/wwwroot/app/development/ruby/1.9.1/gems/therubyracer-0.9.10/ext/v8/gem_make.out
An error occured while installing therubyracer (0.9.10), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install therubyracer -v '0.9.10'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Comment: Take a look at that thread => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6356450/therubyracer-gem-on-windows
It talks about v8lib not being available on win platform. Perhaps you can choose another js backend? execjs supports a couple => https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs

Comment: Thank you Jens.  I've updated my comment above.  execjs is installed, but the error still occurs.  Any idea how I should proceed?

Comment: Yeah, I tried that and get the same error.  I just wish I could tell it to ignore therubyracer... I'm not sure if it will even be possible to run this on a windows machine if I can't get that dependency plucked.

Comment: Another member helped me here: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9421410/telling-bundler-to-exclude-certain-gems-from-a-particular-gems-installation/9422630#9422630

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another member helped me here:

[Telling Bundler to exclude certain gems from a particular gem's installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9421410/telling-bundler-to-exclude-certain-gems-from-a-particular-gems-installation/9422630#9422630)

This is being marked as "trivial" with no content, but I don't want to copy/paste content that isn't mine, so just typing this out.

Answer (score 3):

There is a version of twitter-bootstrap-rails that uses static CSS, without the dependency on therubyracer.  Try this in your Gemfile:

```
gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails', :git => "git://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails.git", :branch => "static"
```