# Telling Bundler to exclude certain gems from a particular gem's installation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, bundler, twitter-bootstrap

Within a gemfile, is there any way to tell Bundler something like:

```
gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails', :exclude therubyracer
```

I need to install twitter-bootstrap-rails but it automatically pulls `therubyracer` in, so `bundle install` fails and bootstrap isn't included in the project since this is a Windows machine.  I installed execjs to no avail.

I tried to list `therubyracer` under production, and `bundle install --without production`, also to no avail.

"[therubyracer gem on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6356450/therubyracer-gem-on-windows)" is also this problem, but none of the suggestions there change the error I'm getting.

My old thread was "[When I do "bundle update", I get an error from a gem not in my gemfile. How do I ignore this dependency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9402784/when-i-do-bundle-update-i-get-an-error-from-a-gem-not-in-my-gemfile-how-do-i#comment11904936_9402784)".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no option for this in Bundler.

So you're left with these options:

- Don't use `twitter-bootstrap-rails`. You can just copy the compiled css and js files into the proper directories under `vendor/assets`. You'll lose the ability to change less variables. Or you can use the `compass_twitter_bootstrap` gem, which uses sass instead of less.
- Get the maintainer of the `less` gem to use `execjs` instead of `commonjs` and `therubyracer`. It would probably mean significant refactoring for the maintainer(s) if at all possible.
- Use the `:platform` option in your Gemfile, to only install on OSX or Linux. Then require the parts you can use by hand, without loading `less`. This probably won't work.

Comment: That's pretty lame :-( Any chance that Bundler will have an exclude feature in near future?

Comment: Wow, this is terrrible. So if someone depends on something you 100% can verify does not get called, you're left with forking the gem to remove the line from the gemfile to avoid using that dependency. Wow.