# Rails Twitter Bootstrap gem failing bundle install due to therubyracer dependency?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to install Twitter-Bootstrap-Rails gem on Mac OSX Lion. I added the twitter-bootsrap line to my Gemfile, but when I run bundle install, it's failing due to an issue with therubyracer gem.

```
....rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p318/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:368:in `try_do': The complier failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
```

I already have developer tools running, and XCode 4.3.2. I'm running Rails 3.2 and Ruby 1.9.2p318.

Any idea why the compiler might be failing for this gem install or how I can fix?

Comment: Probably this [answer][1] will work for you


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9421410/telling-bundler-to-exclude-certain-gems-from-a-particular-gems-installation/9422630#9422630

Comment: Do you have the Xcode command line tools installed? That error message usually includes a reference to a log file that would probably be useful.

Comment: @Andrew Marshall I do have Xcode command line tools installed - I even re-installed but no luck.

Comment: Is there any way to tell which compiler it may be using? GCC or LLVM etc? from your stack trace? http://wellconsidered.be/post/18996655760/therubyracer-compile-error-osx-10-7-lion

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8032824/cant-install-ruby-under-lion-with-rvm-gcc-issues

Answer (score -2):

```
gem install therubyracer
```

or

```
gem 'therubyracer'
```

works for me on linux.