# Gemfile still looking for a gem I removed from Gemfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, bundler, therubyracer

I'm pretty new to Ruby on Rails and I'm still wrapping my head around how it works.  Apologies if this is a simple question, but:

I was following a tutorial about deploying my Rails app to EC2 when they mentioned enabling "therubyracer" gem in my Gemfile.  I've been having trouble getting a server going with this gem in my Gemfile so I removed it, but its still looking for it and erroring on it.

My question is why? Is it cached somewhere that I need to clear out? I ran "bundle install", and "bundle update" and they both crap out on me.  The same when I try starting "rails server"

Heres the output I get when running "rails server" from the terminal.

```
/Users/chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:90:in `block in materialize': Could not find therubyracer-0.10.1 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
from /Users/chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:83:in `map!'
from /Users/chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:83:in `materialize'
from /Users/chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:127:in `specs'
from /Users/chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/environment.rb:27:in `specs'
from /Users/chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rubygems-bundler-1.0.3/lib/rubygems-bundler/noexec.rb:41:in `candidate?'
from /Users/chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rubygems-bundler-1.0.3/lib/rubygems-bundler/noexec.rb:60:in `setup'
from /Users/chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rubygems-bundler-1.0.3/lib/rubygems-bundler/noexec.rb:75:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/chris/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `require'
from /Users/chris/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `rescue in require'
from /Users/chris/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:35:in `require'
from /Users/chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:9:in `<main>'
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [When I do "bundle update", I get an error from a gem not in my gemfile. How do I ignore this dependency?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9402784/when-i-do-bundle-update-i-get-an-error-from-a-gem-not-in-my-gemfile-how-do-i)

Comment: Yeah I saw this after posting it. Sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

Ok stupidly I found a thread after posting this about the exact issue I'm facing.  I'm pretty sure its Twitter Bootstrap related.

[When I do "bundle update", I get an error from a gem not in my gemfile. How do I ignore this dependency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9402784/when-i-do-bundle-update-i-get-an-error-from-a-gem-not-in-my-gemfile-how-do-i)

Comment: Yep, thats exactly what it was.  Disregard this post.