# Unable to install the gem therubyracer

Tags: ruby-on-rails

While running the bundle install command, I encountered the following error:

> Installing libv8 (3.3.10.4) with native extensions
>   Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native
>   extension .
>
> ```
>     D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
> ```
>
> *** extconf.rb failed *** Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check
>   the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may need configuration
>   options.
>
> Provided configuration options:
>           --with-opt-dir
>           --without-opt-dir
>           --with-opt-include
>           --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
>           --with-opt-lib
>           --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
>           --with-make-prog
>           --without-make-prog
>           --srcdir=.
>           --curdir
>           --ruby=D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/bin/ruby Checking for Python...Unable to build libv8: Python not found!
>
> Gem files will remain installed in
>   D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9 .1/gems/libv8-3.3.10.4
>   for inspection. Results logged to
>   D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/libv8-3.3
>   .10.4/ext/libv8/gem_make.out An error occured while installing libv8
>   (3.3.10.4), and Bundler cannot continue.
>
> Make sure that `gem install libv8 -v '3.3.10.4'` succeeds before
>   bundling.

Environment: Ruby 1.9.2 Rails 3.2.1 Gem : 1.8.17
**Gemfile**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

    gem 'rails', '3.2.1'

    gem 'sqlite3'

    gem "heroku"

    group :production do
      gem 'pg'
    end

    gem 'execjs'
    gem 'therubyracer'
    gem 'libv8', '3.3.10.4'


    group :assets do
      gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
      gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
      gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
    end

    gem 'jquery-rails'
```

Can anybody tell me why I am seeing this error, and how to fix it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [therubyracer gem on windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6356450/therubyracer-gem-on-windows)

Answer (score 2):

Did you do `gem install libv8 -v '3.3.10.4'`

You could also try installing python.  For mac see http://www.python.org/getit/mac/

Comment: I have tried this, Still I am getting same error, its looking for Python.

Comment: Basically, I want to upload the my application into Heroku. But The java scripts are not compiled on Heroku environment So i have added few gems to the Gemfile, gem 'execjs' and gem 'therubyracer'. execjs gem is install properly, 'therubyracer' gen is not installing, got the above error.

Comment: If the gem is installed separately and then give 'bundle install', the above issue gets solved.

Comment: Yes, bundle will now use the installed gem.