# Could not find gem 'therubyracer in linux server passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger

```
Could not find gem 'therubyracer (>= 0) ruby' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile. (Bundler::GemNotFound).
```

Comment: And would you consider writing up a little bit more of a question?

Comment: the solution is gem install libv8 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9613201/unable-to-install-the-gem-therubyracer thank's

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add in top of your Gemfile

```
source :rubygems
```