# Unable to install therubyracer-heroku gem for ruby on rails on windows?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to install the gem for ruby and rails in windows. I have tried the below command.

```
gem install therubyracer-heroku -v '0.8.1.pre3'
```

I am unable to install, got the below error.

> D:\Ruby\demo_app>gem install therubyracer-heroku -v '0.8.1.pre3' Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit... Building native
>   extensions.  This could take a while... ERROR:  Error installing
>   therubyracer-heroku:
>           ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
>
> D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb The system cannot find the path specified.
>   extconf.rb failed Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check
>   the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may need configuration
>   options.
>
> Provided configuration options:
>
> ```
>     --with-opt-dir
>     --without-opt-dir
>     --with-opt-include
>     --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
>     --with-opt-lib
>     --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
>     --with-make-prog
>     --without-make-prog
>     --srcdir=.
>     --curdir
>     --ruby=D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/bin/ruby extconf.rb:9:in `<main>': Error compiling V8 (RuntimeError) Compiling V8
> ```
>
> Gem files will remain installed in
>   D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/therubyracer-heroku-0.8.1.pre3
>   for inspection. Results logged to
>   D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/therubyracer-heroku-0.8.1.pre3/ext/v8/gem_make.out

Comment: possible duplicate of [therubyracer gem on windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6356450/therubyracer-gem-on-windows)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `therubyracer` and `therubyracer-heroku` gems are not compatible with Windows.

The gems require `libv8` be compiled for the platform which hasn't been tackled by the gem developers (yet or maybe never will happen)

This gem is used as JavaScript engine which then is used by ExecJS and Rails to minify and perform other tasks on top of your JavaScript.

Windows already have a JavaScript engine (`cscript`) which is available in the `PATH`. ExecJS will detect it.

What you need to do is ensure `therubyracer` or `therubyracer` gem are not installed under Windows.

Since most likely you're using [Bundler](http://gembundler.com/), in your `Gemfile` you will require to define a platform (and a environment if you haven't) to tell Bundler not to install the gem under Windows.

Please look at `platform` option inside [Bundler documentation](http://gembundler.com/man/gemfile.5.html) on how to use it.

One example will be:

```
group :production do
  gem "therubyracer-heroku", :platforms => [:ruby]
end
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I'm a Ruby/Ruby on Rails beginner. How do you let 'rails server' use cscript Javascript runtime? Would you recommend some tutorial for me? Also, do I need to edit some gemfile?