# cannot load such file -- v8 (in E:/work/store/app/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap_and_overrides.css.less)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, twitter-bootstrap-rails

**1)rails new store**

**2)rails g scaffold product name price:decimal --skip-stylesheets**

**3)rake db:migrate**

**4)in Gemfile :**
*gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails', :git => 'git://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails.git'*

**5)bundle install**

**6)rails generate bootstrap:install less**

**7)browser :**

[image]

**after the restart, the error is repeated. Why? I enjoyed instructions:**
https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails

**app/assets/stylesheets/application.css**

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or vendor/assets/stylesheets of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the bottom of the
 * compiled file so the styles you add here take precedence over styles defined in any styles
 * defined in the other CSS/SCSS files in this directory. It is generally better to create a new
 * file per style scope.
 *
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 */
```

**app/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap_and_overrides.css.less**

```
@import "twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap";

// Set correct font paths
@glyphiconsEotPath: font-url("glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot");
@glyphiconsEotPath_iefix: font-url("glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix");
@glyphiconsWoffPath: font-url("glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff");
@glyphiconsTtfPath: font-url("glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf");
@glyphiconsSvgPath: font-url("glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons_halflingsregular");

// Set the Font Awesome (Font Awesome is default. You can disable by commenting below lines)
@fontAwesomeEotPath: font-url("fontawesome-webfont.eot");
@fontAwesomeEotPath_iefix: font-url("fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix");
@fontAwesomeWoffPath: font-url("fontawesome-webfont.woff");
@fontAwesomeTtfPath: font-url("fontawesome-webfont.ttf");
@fontAwesomeSvgPath: font-url("fontawesome-webfont.svg#fontawesomeregular");

// Font Awesome
@import "fontawesome/font-awesome";

// Glyphicons
//@import "twitter/bootstrap/glyphicons.less";

// Your custom LESS stylesheets goes here
//
// Since bootstrap was imported above you have access to its mixins which
// you may use and inherit here
//
// If you'd like to override bootstrap's own variables, you can do so here as well
// See http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/customize.html#variables for their names and documentation
//
// Example:
// @link-color: #ff0000;
```

**I added : gem "therubyracer", gem "less-rails"**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.1.8'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer',  platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin]

gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails', :git => 'git://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails.git'
gem "therubyracer"
gem "less-rails"
```

**console error during installation:**

```
C:\tools\rubies\ruby-2.1.5-p273\bin\ruby.exe -e $stdout.sync=true;$stderr.sync=true;load($0=ARGV.shift) E:/work/store/bin/bundle install
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/............
Fetching additional metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...
Using rake 10.4.2
Using i18n 0.7.0
Using json 1.8.3
Using minitest 5.7.0
Using thread_safe 0.3.5
Using tzinfo 1.2.2
Using activesupport 4.1.8
Using builder 3.2.2
Using erubis 2.7.0
Using actionview 4.1.8
Using rack 1.5.5
Using rack-test 0.6.3
Using actionpack 4.1.8
Using mime-types 2.6.1
Using mail 2.6.3
Using actionmailer 4.1.8
Using activemodel 4.1.8
Using arel 5.0.1.20140414130214
Using activerecord 4.1.8
Using bundler 1.7.11
Using coffee-script-source 1.9.1.1
Using execjs 2.5.2
Using coffee-script 2.4.1
Using thor 0.19.1
Using railties 4.1.8
Using coffee-rails 4.0.1
Using commonjs 0.2.7
Using hike 1.2.3
Using multi_json 1.11.2
Using jbuilder 2.3.1
Using jquery-rails 3.1.3
Using less 2.6.0
Using tilt 1.4.1
Using sprockets 2.12.4
Using less-rails 2.7.0

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    C:/tools/rubies/ruby-2.1.5-p273/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb 
creating Makefile
which: no python in (.;c:\tools\ruby-devkits\ruby-20\bin;c:\tools\ruby-devkits\ruby-20\mingw\bin;C:\tools\rubies\ruby-2.1.5-p273\bin;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\tools\rubies\ruby-2.1.5-p273\Ruby21\bin;C:\Ruby21\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\;c:\tools\uru;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Users\vitalij\AppData\Roaming\npm)
���⥬� �� 㤠���� ���� 㪠����� ����.
which: no python in (.;c:\tools\ruby-devkits\ruby-20\bin;c:\tools\ruby-devkits\ruby-20\mingw\bin;C:\tools\rubies\ruby-2.1.5-p273\bin;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\tools\rubies\ruby-2.1.5-p273\Ruby21\bin;C:\Ruby21\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\;c:\tools\uru;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Users\vitalij\AppData\Roaming\npm)
C:/tools/rubies/ruby-2.1.5-p273/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.11/ext/libv8/builder.rb:81:in `setup_python!': libv8 requires python 2 to be installed in order to build, but it is currently not available (RuntimeError)
    from C:/tools/rubies/ruby-2.1.5-p273/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.11/ext/libv8/builder.rb:55:in `block in build_libv8!'
    from C:/tools/rubies/ruby-2.1.5-p273/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.11/ext/libv8/builder.rb:52:in `chdir'
    from C:/tools/rubies/ruby-2.1.5-p273/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.11/ext/libv8/builder.rb:52:in `build_libv8!'
    from C:/tools/rubies/ruby-2.1.5-p273/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.11/ext/libv8/location.rb:24:in `install!'
    from extconf.rb:7:in `<main>'

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in C:/tools/rubies/ruby-2.1.5-p273/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.11 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/tools/rubies/ruby-2.1.5-p273/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/extensions/x86-mingw32/2.1.0/libv8-3.16.14.11/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing libv8 (3.16.14.11), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install libv8 -v '3.16.14.11'` succeeds before bundling.

Process finished with exit code 5
```

Comment: Please post contents of manifest file `/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css`.  It sounds like it contains a directive to load the subject file and that file does not exist.

Comment: I mean open that file, copy the contents, edit your original post and paste the file contents there so we can see them.  Please do not post files into comments as this is pretty hard to read.

Comment: added the contents of that file

Comment: OK since you have `*= require_tree .`, Sprockets will attempt to load every file in that same folder.  What other files are in that folder?

Comment: app/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap_and_overrides.css.less

Comment: You need to add these gems to your gemfile and bundle install:  gem "therubyracer"
gem "less-rails"

Comment: console error during installation

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82983/discussion-between-steve-klein-and-vitalik-andrysha).

Comment: I used another gem :
gem 'bootstrap-sass'    , and it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I used another gem :**[bootstrap-sass](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass)

**and it worked**

[Warning using twitter-bootstrap-rails generators on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11703686/warning-using-twitter-bootstrap-rails-generators-on-windows)