# is there a way of installing therubyracer in windows?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cygwin, therubyracer

Is there a way of installing therubyracer gem i.e required to run a RoR project in windows?

I've tried normal way, but it wouldn't and then i tried installing cygwin and then tried installing gem, but still no luck,

Anyone successful in installing this in windows?
I can even try the hard methods also (if there're any possible solutions)

Comment: Did you try google? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6356450/therubyracer-gem-on-windows

Comment: yes, of course, as i can see the answers dated back 1year, so i thought it would be a good idea to check, and even in there they said it can be  installed in *nix environments, so tried cygwin but no luck.

Answer (score 3):

I used [therubyracer_for_windows](https://github.com/hiranpeiris/therubyracer_for_windows).  It works for me.

Comment: this worked for me -- windows 7, RailsInstaller.

I had also tried adding `:platform => :ruby` [so](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6796100) and, trying to resolve libv8 issues, `gem install libv8 -v '3.16.14.7' -- --with-system-v8` [so](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18648054)

Answer (score 0):

If you need a JS runtime for asset compilation (and other tasks), on Windows it's perfectly safe to simply omit the gem in your Gemfile.

Windows already has a JS runtime, and as far as I am aware, Rails makes use of it when it detects it.

Have a look at the description here, I think you will find it informative.

https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs

Comment: Reason i need is to have twitter-bootstrap gem , and I don't want it to be static, so if there's a hard way please do tell. It keeps on asking me for rubyracer for .LESS files.

Comment: I can tell you that for a rather simple project I did recently in Rails, the requirement was that a junior developer inheriting the project must be able to code it under Windows. To do that, I commented out `therubyracer` gem and had to specify a concrete version for another gem, like this: `gem "eventmachine", "1.0.0.rc.4"`. That was good enough for the asset pipeline to start working. On your topic though: did you implement the recommendations in twitter-bootstrap-rails gem documentation on using it with and without LESS?

Comment: What changes should i make it to http://pastebin.com/4WWKwafN , so that my LESS files work in windows, I can't change anything other than Gemfile (it's a project requirement). Thanks for your time

Comment: Let's start here -- are you still receiving an error with this Gemfile and if so, can you paste it?

Comment: yes, ofcourse, as you see gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails' has dependency of rubyracer, I can't install it.