# I can't run "bundle install" due to libv8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am running this on Windows 10.
I am trying build this repository (incase the Gemfile and Gemfile.lock are helpful):
https://github.com/huginn/huginn

```
Error:

C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/libv8-7.3.492.27.1/ext/libv8

C:/Ruby24-x64/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20200209-30680-1j9g8t0.rb extconf.rb

creating Makefile

The system cannot find the path specified.

The system cannot find the path specified.

The system cannot find the path specified.

C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/libv8-7.3.492.27.1/ext/libv8/builder.rb:57:in

`setup_python!': libv8 requires python 2 to be installed in order to build, but

it is currently not available (RuntimeError)

from

C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/libv8-7.3.492.27.1/ext/libv8/builder.rb:39:in

`build_libv8!'

from

C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/libv8-7.3.492.27.1/ext/libv8/location.rb:24:in

`install!'

from extconf.rb:7:in `<main>'

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in

C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/libv8-7.3.492.27.1 for inspection.

Results logged to

C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.4.0/libv8-7.3.492.27.1/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing libv8 (7.3.492.27.1), and Bundler cannot

continue.

Make sure that `gem install libv8 -v '7.3.492.27.1' --source

'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before bundling.

In Gemfile:

mini_racer was resolved to 0.2.9, which depends on

libv8
```

What ever I google, the top answer is always the same:
I tried both:

> gem install libv8 -v '3.16.14.1' -- --with-system-v8

or

> gem install libv8 -v '3.11.8.13' -- --with-system-v8

[gem install libv8 --version '3.11.8.17' on ruby (windows)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16514758/gem-install-libv8-version-3-11-8-17-on-ruby-windows)
[libv8 required python 2 to be installed in order to build - Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17346681/libv8-required-python-2-to-be-installed-in-order-to-build-windows/22579851)
[therubyracer - Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23536893/therubyracer-gemextbuilderror-error-failed-to-build-gem-native-extension)

I see the Gemfile.lock has this

```
libv8 (7.3.492.27.1) 
..... 
mini_racer (0.2.9) 
  libv8 (>= 6.9.411)
```

So I assume the Gemfile.lock is causing this to install the version I don't want. But I don't know how to resolve this.

I am still learning Ruby and this is my first big project I decided to start trying out.

Also I do have Python 2 on my computer. So I'm not sure why it's saying it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at the Gemfile it states that the mini_racer gem, which is the sticking point here, is an optional gem, so it might be worth commentating it out and trying to bundle again.  See if you get anywhere.

Also if mini_racer is anything like therubyracer, is not really needed on windows as it has JScript built in, so it doesn't need another javascript runtime.