# How to install therubyracer gem on 10.10 Yosemite?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I don't manage to install therubyracer gem on Yosemite 10.10.

Here is the log:

```
11:53  $ gem install libv8 -v '3.16.14.3' -- --with-system-v8


Building native extensions with: '--with-system-v8'
This could take a while...
Successfully installed libv8-3.16.14.3
Parsing documentation for libv8-3.16.14.3
Installing ri documentation for libv8-3.16.14.3
Done installing documentation for libv8 after 0 seconds
1 gem installed


02:05  $ gem install therubyracer -v '0.12.1' -- --with-system-v8


Building native extensions with: '--with-system-v8'
This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing therubyracer:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.1.2/bin/ruby extconf.rb --with-system-v8
checking for main() in -lpthread... yes
checking for main() in -lobjc... yes
checking for v8.h... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.1.2/bin/ruby
    --with-pthreadlib
    --without-pthreadlib
    --with-objclib
    --without-objclib
    --enable-debug
    --disable-debug
    --with-v8-dir
    --without-v8-dir
    --with-v8-include
    --without-v8-include=${v8-dir}/include
    --with-v8-lib
    --without-v8-lib=${v8-dir}/lib
/usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3/ext/libv8/location.rb:50:in `configure': You have chosen to use the version of V8 found on your system (Libv8::Location::System::NotFoundError)
and *not* the one that is bundle with the libv8 rubygem. However,
it could not be located. please make sure you have a version of
v8 that is compatible with 3.16.14.3 installed. You may
need to special --with-v8-dir options if it is in a non-standard
location

thanks,
The Mgmt

    from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3/lib/libv8.rb:7:in `configure_makefile'
    from extconf.rb:32:in `'

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/therubyracer-0.12.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-14/2.1.0-static/therubyracer-0.12.1/gem_make.out
```

Comment: You too are running in problems with Yosemite :D

Comment: I know, I like to be an adventurer :-P

Comment: I'm also having trouble with this i tried doing brew install v8, too but didn't work

Answer (score 68, accepted):

```
git clone https://github.com/cowboyd/libv8.git
cd libv8
bundle install
bundle exec rake clean build binary
gem install pkg/libv8-3.16.14.3-x86_64-darwin-12.gem #note that libv8 version may change, so tab through files in pkg/, also remember to use the one with version specified
```

then just bundle your project gems

this is the only way it worked for me on 10.10 (ruby 2.1.2)

Comment: thanks but this is libv8, i was speaking of therubyracer gem.

Comment: this is what you need to avoid issues with therubyracer

Comment: I don't care if I'm breaking the rules. I can't thank you enough. You have saved a huge project deadline for me.

Comment: Thank's, it work for me, just for copy/paste guy like me, we are now at gem install pkg/libv8-3.16.14.7-x86_64-darwin-14.gem

Comment: Note that you can build the specific version you need by doing a `git checkout tags/v3.x.y.z` (where x, y, and z are the minor, etc., version numbers you need) after cloning.

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that if you're using a Gemfile and still having trouble installing therubyracer, it's probably because there's a different version of libv8 that's already been added to the Gemfile.lock. Just add `gem 'libv8', '3.16.14.3'` (or whatever is the exact version of the libv8 that you just manually installed), and run bundle update libv8. That should then install therubyracer.

Comment: I having issues `compiling v8 for x64`. When I run 'bundle exec rake clean build binary' I get `Unable to find a compiler officially supported by v8.
It is recommended to use GCC v4.4 or higher`. Any Ideas?

Comment: Please also see the other answer below by Wylkon, with currently 214 votes which suggests installing v8 as well. This worked for me.

Answer (score 260):

```
gem uninstall libv8
brew install v8
gem install therubyracer
gem install libv8 -v '3.16.14.3' -- --with-system-v8
```

this is the only way it worked for me on 10.10 (ruby 2.1.2)

Or try `gem install libv8 -v 'XX.XX.XX' -- --with-system-v8` adding the version of the gem :)

UPDATE for Mac OS Catalina:

```
brew tap homebrew/versions
brew install v8@3.15
brew link --force v8@3.15
gem install libv8 -v 'XX.XX.XX' -- --with-system-v8
gem install therubyracer
```

Comment: Yep, this is the one that helps without any weirdness. Even though you may just be getting a libv8 error, do this! thanks.

Comment: Yep.  This is the right way to do it.  Specially if you had rebuilt your ruby with the latest 10.10 command line tools.

Comment: Worked for me with Ruby 2.1.3 in OS X Yosemite.

Comment: this worked for 2.0.0! Thanks mate! now I'm facing another error. rmagick

Comment: In addition to this, If you are using bundler and have a Gemfile, you may need to adjust it to the latest version you just installed. For example, I had to (on OS X Yosemite) do the following: `gem 'therubyracer', '0.12.1'` (added the version). Then removed Gemfile.lock and did `bundle install`. It works fine.

Comment: This worked for me as well, on El Capitan.  I think this is a lot simpler and should be the accepted answer.

Comment: I didn't need to do the brew bit. Simply running gem install libv8 -v '3.16.14.3' -- --with-system-v8 worked for me.

Comment: Best Solutions for any mac, really thanks for therubyracer

Comment: Worked like a charm on macOS Sierra (10.12.3) as well.

Comment: This worked for libv8-3.16.14.7 / therubyracer-0.12.1 with ruby 1.9.3p551 on High Sierra 10.13.6.  Thanks!

Comment: Worked for me in MacOS Mojave

Answer (score 44):

None of the answers work for me this time. I have too use this:

```
brew tap homebrew/versions
brew install v8-315

gem install libv8 -v '3.16.14.13' -- --with-system-v8
gem install therubyracer -- --with-v8-dir=/usr/local/opt/v8-315

bundle install
```

Seen on the rubyracer Github issues.

Hope it helps someone else.

Comment: Thanks for this. None of the other approaches will work on El Capitan using modern versions of the dependent gems. (therubyracer is woefully behind libv8 at this point.)

Comment: Sadly you're right... This error is driving me crazy each time I change ruby version.

Comment: tap homebrew/versions has now been deprecated so this no longer works.

Comment: Actually, `gem install therubyracer -- --with-v8-dir=$(brew --prefix v8-315)` works better for me. The dir in my mac is actually `/usr/local/opt/v8@3.15`

Answer (score 26):

Maybe it will be useful for someone but I had problems installing therubyracer (because of the problems with libv8) the solution was to *uninstall* all the libv8 that I had installed. Install therubyracer

```
$ gem uninstall libv8
$ gem install therubyracer -v '0.12.0'
Fetching: libv8-3.16.14.7-x86_64-darwin-14.gem ( 57%)
Fetching: libv8-3.16.14.7-x86_64-darwin-14.gem (100%)
Successfully installed libv8-3.16.14.7-x86_64-darwin-14
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed therubyracer-0.12.0
2 gems installed
```

I hope this helps someone.

Comment: This seems to have worked for me. However I would like to point out that the best way to uninstall all versions of the libv8 gem is: `gem uninstall libv8 -a -x`. If you use a ruby version manager (e.g. `rbenv`, etc) then this works for only your current version of ruby (in case that wasn't obvious).

Comment:  this solution worked for me - El Capitan 10.11.6, Ruby - ruby 1.9.3p448 (2013-06-27 revision 41675)

Answer (score 13):

It seems like this has been fixed upstream. What worked for me and @aurels and @Mike Causer and @Juanda was:

```
bundle update libv8
```

Answer (score 7):

This worked for me very well on my Yosemite and Ruby 2.1.5 (Ruby through RVM)

```
gem install libv8 -v '3.16.14.3' -- --with-system-v8
```

Earlier it was giving me error `Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.` for libv8 gem version 3.16.14.3

Answer (score 7):

Only this works for me in my Yosemite, Ruby 2.1.2:

```
gem install libv8 -v '3.16.14.3' -- --with-system-v8
brew link --overwrite v8-315 --force
gem install therubyracer -v '0.12.2' -- --with-system-v8
```

Comment: Only this solved problem installing rubyracer for `ruby 1.9.3p484` and `rubyracer 0.12.3`

Answer (score 6):

I was able to proceed with ruby racer after `rm Gemfile.lock`

beforehand:
I installed v8 via `brew install v8`, and then did `gem install libv8 -v '3.16.14.3' -- --with-system-v8`

and I am running 10.10 Yosemite

Answer (score 4):

They have corrected this issue in the most recent version of libv8.  See: https://github.com/cowboyd/libv8/issues/123

You should install from the github repo, in rails I added a line to my gemfile like this `gem "libv8", git: "git://github.com/cowboyd/libv8.git", submodules: true`

EDIT:

This apparently only solves some of the problem.  I installed the new version of libv8, but now the rubyracer is still looking for the other one I think?  Still looking into it.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue on Yosemite. My solution is similar to what appears above.

Use `gem uninstall libv8` to remove anything that might be installed.

Leave therubyracer in your Gemfile, but remove any explicit reference to libv8.

Run `bundle install`.

libv8 then installed fine as a dependency.

Comment: This was my issue. I had multiple version of libv8 fighting each other. Clearing them out and letting bundler resolve the dependency was the right thing to do.

Answer (score 2):

Updated answer for 2018.

I'm on High Sierra, on Homebrew 1.6.1

```
brew install v8-315

gem install libv8 -v '3.16.14.13' -- --with-system-v8
gem install therubyracer -- --with-v8-dir=/usr/local/opt/v8@3.15/
```

Is what worked for me.

Credit goes to @coding-addicted for his [original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36388150/2506667).

Answer (score 1):

After hours of trying simply upgrading ruby worked:

```
brew install ruby
```

and then adding the following to gem file:

```
gem 'libv8'  
gem 'therubyracer'
```

Answer (score 1):

A heads up to anyone that might have been having my issue: I ended up uninstalling my ruby version in RVM and then reinstalling it. That seemed to use the correct dependancies in the latest version of xcode tools for compiling ruby.

```
rvm list
rvm uninstall ruby-x.x.x
rvm install ruby-x.x.x
```

Answer (score 0):

I did the following

```
gem install therubyracer
```

which now installs `therubyracer 0.12.1` which installs the dependency `libv8 (3.16.14.7 x86_64-darwin-14)` which installed with no errors.

I did this using `ruby 2.1.5` which I installed via:

```
CC=/usr/bin/gcc rbenv install 2.1.5
```

which I did after running `brew upgrade ruby-builds`.

After installing `ruby 2.1.5`, I also ran

```
gem upgrade --system
```

to get `rubygems-update 2.4.5`

Answer (score 0):

this happens due to some conflicts with the libv8 as well, although you can just assign a version to the rubyracer and it will be installed:

change the following in the gemfile:

gem 'therubyracer', '~> 0.12.1'

and do bundle install

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me, based on the following comment,

https://github.com/cowboyd/therubyracer/issues/304#issuecomment-62046085

was to remove Gemfile.lock and then run bundle install

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me following Jakub Troszok's solution above with just a minor change

```
gem uninstall libv8
gem install therubyracer -v '0.12.1'
    Fetching: libv8-3.16.14.19-x86_64-darwin-18.gem (100%)
    Successfully installed libv8-3.16.14.19-x86_64-darwin-18
    Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
    Successfully installed therubyracer-0.12.1
    Parsing documentation for libv8-3.16.14.19-x86_64-darwin-18
    Installing ri documentation for libv8-3.16.14.19-x86_64-darwin-18
    Parsing documentation for therubyracer-0.12.1
    Installing ri documentation for therubyracer-0.12.1
    Done installing documentation for libv8, therubyracer after 0 seconds
    2 gems installed
gem install libv8 -v '3.16.14.17' -- --with-system-v8  (if the libv8 version required for your project is different from the one installed by rubyracer)
bundle install
```

Comment: Please point out what the minor change is and try to explain why it's working. Since you're answering a 4 years old question, you should also add some detail on applicable versions (your answer might not have been relevant then).

Answer (score 0):

Using homebrew's directory of v8 for `--with-v8-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/v8@3.15/3.15.11.18_1`, instead of `/usr/local/opt/v8-315`, is what worked for me, in coding addicted's answer.

This is visible in the `Summary` of the brew install command, `brew install v8-315`.