# Ruby bundle install tries to compile libv8 gem already installed

Tags: ruby, macos, rubygems, libv8

When doing `bundle install` on a client's Ruby project, I'm getting this error:

```
An error occurred while installing libv8 (3.16.14.3), and Bundler
cannot continue.
```

However, when I do `gem list`, that gem and version are clearly already there:

```
$ gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***
...
libv8 (3.16.14.3)
...
```

Note: `bundle install` used to work until I updated OSX from Mavericks to Yosemite.  I had to do a workaround in order to get the libv8 gem to compile, using "[How to install therubyracer gem on 10.10 Yosemite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24081473/how-to-install-therubyracer-gem-on-10-10-yosemite/25757171#25757171)"

Why is bundle trying to re-compile something already installed, and how can I fix this?

Update: the environment

```
$ gem env RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.4.5
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.2.0 (2014-12-25 patchlevel 0) [x86_64-darwin14]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /Users/me/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-darwin-14
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0
     - /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@global
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/bin
     - /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@global/bin
     - /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/bin
     - /usr/local/sbin
     - /Applications/Postgres93.app/Contents/MacOS/bin
     - /Applications/My Applications/redis-2.6.7/src
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/bin
     - /bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /sbin
     - /opt/X11/bin
     - /usr/local/git/bin
     - /usr/local/go/bin
     - /Users/me/Documents/projects/Go/bin
     - /Users/me/.rvm/bin
```

Comment: So, how is the user's Ruby environment set up? Run `gem env` and append the output to your question. Format it so it's readable.

Comment: Answer for this is same as that of the following problem : 
[Link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27868209/bundle-install-path-vendor-cache/28462052#28462052