# gem install therubyracer -v '0.12.0' on osx yosemite not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos

Hi here is my console log,

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while... 
ERROR:  Error installing therubyracer:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for main() in -lpthread... yes
checking for main() in -lobjc... yes 
checking for v8.h... no 
*** extconf.rb failed *** 
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of 
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more 
details.  You may need configuration options. 

Provided configuration options: 
    --with-opt-dir 
    --with-opt-include 
--without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include 
--with-opt-lib 
--without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib 
--with-make-prog 
--without-make-prog 
--srcdir=. 
--curdir 
--ruby=/Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin/ruby 
--with-pthreadlib 
--without-pthreadlib 
--with-objclib 
--without-objclib 
--enable-debug 
--disable-debug 
--with-v8-dir 
--without-v8-dir 
--with-v8-include 
--without-v8-include=${v8-dir}/include 
--with-v8-lib 
--without-v8-lib=${v8-dir}/ 
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@projVer2.3/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3/ext/libv8    /location.rb:50:in `configure': You have chosen to use the version of V8 found on your system (Libv8::Location::System::NotFoundError) 
and *not* the one that is bundle with the libv8 rubygem. However, 
it could not be located. please make sure you have a version of 
v8 that is compatible with 3.16.14.3 installed. You may 
need to special --with-v8-dir options if it is in a non-standard 
location 

thanks, 
The Mgmt 

from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@projVer2.3/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3/lib/libv8.rb:7:in `configure_makefile' 
from extconf.rb:32:in `<main>' 


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@projVer2.3/gems/therubyracer-0.12.1 for inspection. 
Results logged to /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@projVer2.3/gems/therubyracer-    0.12.1/ext/v8/gem_make.out 
FDLMC060:helpkit user$
```

I tried a lot of links which install libv8 via homebrew and then tried to install therubyracer but no help.

and i tried this link as well..

[How to install therubyracer gem on 10.10 Yosemite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24081473/how-to-install-therubyracer-gem-on-10-10-yosemite?rq=1)

but throwed errors while installing v8 itself.

The switch --with-system-v8 installs the libv8 
but its not installing therubyracer -v '0.12.0'

OS -> OS X Yosemite

installed apple-gcc 4.2

and made export on CC,CXX

Please Help me to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

Try to

```
gem install therubyracer -v '0.12.0' -- --with-v8-dir=/path/to/v8
```

But before you should have v8 installed on your system

Comment: I tried this .. but no help..  and I installed libv8 with -- --with-system-v8 option and gave the location of the libv8 gem as                                                    --with-v8-dir=/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@projVer2.3/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Stanislav for trying to help me.

I exactly did this at last,

Uninstalled all libv8 related gems using
    "gem uninstall libv8 -a -x"
and then removed the Gemfile.lock using "rm -rf Gemfile.lock"
and tried
    "bundle install"
it worked!!!!

Comment: Congrats :) Some strange bug, but its great that it works now