# Compatibility issues between therubyracer and libv8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, v8, libv8

Facing compatibility issues between 'therubyracer-0.12.1', 'libv8-3.16.14.0' and 'v8'. Which gem versions will solve this issue?

Comment: This question may solve your issue
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23536893/installing-libv8-and-therubyracer-gems-on-mavericks-with-system-v8-installation

Answer (score 0):

This has worked for me a few times when battling with this problem.

Install `libv8` manually in the terminal -with system:

```
gem install libv8 -v '3.16.14.3' -- --with-system-v8
```

Do the same for `therubyracer`

```
gem install therubyracer
```

Then include `therubyracer` as usual in your Gemfile.