# bootstrap and installing libv8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, libv8

when I run bundle install
i have this error:

Installing libv8 (3.16.14.3)
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension
.

```
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
```

creating Makefile
Le chemin d'accès spécifié est introuvable.
Le chemin d'accès spécifié est introuvable.
Le chemin d'accès spécifié est introuvable.
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3/ext/libv8/b
uilder.rb:58:in `setup_python!': libv8 requires python 2 to be installed in orde
r to build, but it is currently not available (RuntimeError)
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.
3/ext/libv8/builder.rb:42:in`block in build_libv8!'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.
3/ext/libv8/builder.rb:40:in `chdir'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.
3/ext/libv8/builder.rb:40:in`build_libv8!'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.
3/ext/libv8/location.rb:24:in `install!'
        from extconf.rb:7:in`'

Gem files will remain installed in C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0
.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/libv8-3.1
6.14.3/ext/libv8/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing libv8 (3.16.14.3), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install libv8 -v '3.16.14.3'` succeeds before bundling.

Comment: can you post your Gemfile please ?

Comment: similar problem here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16514758/gem-install-libv8-version-3-11-8-17-on-ruby-windows?rq=1

Comment: my gemfile:




gem 'rails', '4.0.3'


gem 'sqlite3'

gem 'devise'

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

  
  gem 'therubyracer'

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
  gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails'
  gem 'less-rails'
  gem 'libv8'
end




gem 'jquery-rails'


gem 'turbolinks'


gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'

group :doc do

  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end