# Twitter-bootstrap-rails gem in windows 7 issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, devise

I am trying to use twitter-bootstrail-rails gem to style my devise sign in pages and custom pages. I have followed the screencasts and included the required gem (gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails'

```
gem 'therubyracer', :platform => :ruby
# gem 'therubyracer', '~> 0.10.2'#therubyracer
gem 'libv8', '3.16.14.3'

gem 'less-rails')in my gem file. I am on Windows 7.
```

All my gems are installed successfully installed but when i navigate to http://localhost:3000/users/sign_up or any page, I am getting this error.Kindly help me resolve this issue as i am struck with this for long time..

cannot load such file -- v8
  (in C:/Sites/konavsa/app/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap_and_overrides.css.less)
Extracted source (around line #6):

Konavsa

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16514758/gem-install-libv8-version-3-11-8-17-on-ruby-windows

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
gem 'libv8', '~> 3.11.8.3', :platform => :ruby
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this error before and that made me switch ruby/rails development to linux. I still program in Windows, but i'm using [Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/) +
 [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) to run the project on a linux environment.

Unfortunately some (few) gems doesn't work very well on Windows. So I made the switch. Anyway, that's some things that you can try before "making the move" (although I suggest that you do it anyway, so you can isolate your running environment while still using your favorite IDE at Windows/OS X):

1. **Try to install nodeJS**. Sometimes it solves the problem, although I cannot guarantee nothing.
2. Don't use LESS. Use SASS instead, since it's Rails' default for the asset pipeline.
3. Again. Switch to [Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/) +
   [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) or even [Docker](https://www.docker.com/). There are plenty of tutorials how to setup your project using them.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, for Twitter bootstrap without therubyracer gem on windows

Try add this lines on your Gemfile

```
# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'bootstrap-sass-extras'
gem "twitter-bootstrap-rails"
```

type bundle install