# Ruby on Rails 4 in Windows 7: Bundle install using wrong therubyracer gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, therubyracer

I'm trying to run `bundle install` for a Ruby on Rails project in Windows 7 64 bits, but I'm not able to do it because of the `therubyracer` gem. I developed it in Ubuntu, but I'll need to run it as production  in a Windows 7 computer.

After searching, I found that I should use this gem here: https://github.com/eakmotion/therubyracer_for_windows/blob/master .  It seems to have installed the `therubyracer-0.11.0beta1-x86-mingw32` in my gems. I have also installed the libv8 using `gem install libv8 -v '3.16.14.7' -- --with-system-v8`, as suggested in [gem install libv8 --version '3.11.8.17' on ruby (windows)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16514758/gem-install-libv8-version-3-11-8-17-on-ruby-windows)

However, even after I follow the installation instructions of that gem the `bundle install` still try to install the `therubyracer` gem (version 0.12.1). So, my question is: **how can I run bundle install using the therubyracer gem I manually installed?**

Versions: ruby 2.1.5, rails 4.1.8, installed using Rails Installer http://www.railsinstaller.org/en

Relevant lines of the Gemfile:

```
gem "therubyracer"
gem "less-rails"
gem "twitter-bootstrap-rails"
```

If I exchange `"therubyracer"` for `"therubyracer_for_windows"`, I get an error message `Could not find gem 'therubyracer_for_windows (>= 0) ruby' in the gems available on this machine.` when I try to do a `bundle install`.

The error message for `bundle install`:

```
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/ther
ubyracer-0.12.1/ext/v8
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20160211-944-u6p7vs.rb ext
conf.rb
checking for main() in -lpthread... no
checking for v8.h... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/bin/ruby
        --with-pthreadlib
        --without-pthreadlib
        --enable-debug
        --disable-debug
        --with-v8-dir
        --without-v8-dir
        --with-v8-include
        --without-v8-include=${v8-dir}/include
        --with-v8-lib
        --without-v8-lib=${v8-dir}/lib
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.7/ext/libv8/l
ocation.rb:50:in `configure': You have chosen to use the version of V8 found on
your system (Libv8::Location::System::NotFoundError)
and *not* the one that is bundle with the libv8 rubygem. However,
it could not be located. please make sure you have a version of
v8 that is compatible with 3.16.14.7 installed. You may
need to special --with-v8-dir options if it is in a non-standard
location

thanks,
The Mgmt

        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.
7/lib/libv8.rb:7:in `configure_makefile'
        from extconf.rb:32:in `<main>'

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can
 be found here:

  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/extensions/x86-mingw32/2.1.0/t
herubyracer-0.12.1/mkmf.log
```

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying the version in the gemfile, like:

```
gem "therubyracer", "0.11.0beta1"
```

I've at least had success getting the bundle install to complete that way.

Comment: For what I remember, I tried to do that, but maybe I did it with a wrong therubyracer version. Whenever I can, I'll try this again.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: @BrianHellekin I had run into this with a coworker's windows machine, but even after getting it to build I was getting some crashes running any bootstrap rails code that was trying to include V8. Eventually I just gave up and used a vm

Comment: I tried again, without success. When I tried the last time I gave up too and instead I had success with a VM running Ubuntu or CentOS - even Cygwin failed...