# "gem install therubyracer" fails with error message "libv8 requires python 2 to be installed in order to build"

Tags: ruby, therubyracer, railsinstaller-windows

I am following a tutorial for using Ruby and Sinatra.

I am using Windows 10. I downloaded RailsInstaller and I was following a section where I need to install the gems `coffee-script` and `therubyracer`. `coffee-script` installed but not `therubyracer`, I get an error like this...
['therubyracer' error installation image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LgPvn.png)

I tried to install the gem `libv8` but that didn't work for me either. I get this error...
['libv8' error installation image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LDeTn.png)

How can I resolve these errors and install `therubyracer` on Windows 10?

Comment: In order to be traceable online you need to add the errors inside the question, not as an image.

Comment: One of the dependencies listed in your error message for therubyracer is python2 (you have python3 installed it says). You should try installing python2 and then try to re-install therubyracer.

Comment: Like @JeroenHeier said, don't post screenshots of images. Screenshots are not helpful (for a lot of reasons). The errors you received are in plaintext; copy and paste the errors into your question and format them as a code block so we can see them directly in your post.

Comment: The error message says that you don't have Python 2 installed. Did you try installing Python 2?

Comment: I have installed Python 2.7, but the error still persists.

Answer (score 0):

Download the python 2.7 installer for Windows from https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-2715/ and run it. After python 2.7 has been installed, retry `gem install therubyracer`.

Update:

Since you said you have done this and it still doesn't work, please consider reading the options at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16514758/gem-install-libv8-version-3-11-8-17-on-ruby-windows) as well.

Comment: I followed the link you sent me and I followed the options, and then I required the files, and I got this error when running it...

C:\Users\joelg\Desktop\GitMe\RubySinatra\SinatraExcercise\SinatraCH6>ruby main.rb
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:68:in `require': 126: The specified module could not be found.   - C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/therubyracer-0.11.0beta1-x86-mingw32/lib/v8/init.so (LoadError)

Comment: Does the file `C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/therubyracer-0.11.0beta1-x86-mingw32/lib/v8/init.so` exist?

Comment: Yes it does, I followed the directory and still nothing, and its right there

Comment: Try adding `C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/therubyracer-0.11.0beta1-x86-mingw32/lib/v8/` to your `PATH` and retry the operation.

Comment: This is the point where I recommend you install [WSL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10) and do this on Linux because the problems you're experiencing are the exact reason people don't use Windows and Ruby together.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I switched to WSL, and everything works, but now I have another issue with LoadError regarding dm-postgres-adapter, already posted a question about it if you want to look, thanks again.