# Developing ROR between Windows and Ubuntu machines

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, windows, rubygems, ubuntu-12.04

I would like to develop my app between two machines, work (Windows) and home (Ubuntu). The first issue I have run into is windows needing

```
gem libv8
```

Which won't install at the moment. Further investigation has revealed that I need to install

```
 ActivePython version 2.7.2.5
```

then run:

```
gem install libv8 --version 3.11.8.0
```

It seems that Ubuntu (Linux) comes with its own JavaScript runtime installed so doesn't need the Python files.

My question is that if I install the libv8 gem will it have any effect on my Ubuntu setup when I merge work done between the two platforms?

Has anyone had any issues working with two platforms on the same project?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6359265/44620

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows can sometimes be a bit of pain for RoR development. On your Windows machine, would it be an option to install Oracle VM VirtualBox with an Ubuntu image? Is that an option instead? Might make your development environment more consistent as well if you use Ubuntu at home and in the office...

I doubt that adding another gem will make much difference - as long as you specify all your dependencies in your Gemfile it should work fine on whatever platform you're developing on (assuming you can get everything to install)

Comment: Think that may turn out to be the option, but wanted clarification on whether adding gems in windows platform would effect ubuntu. thanks for the answer

Comment: Is it possible to simply add the libv8 gem outside of your Gemfile?
`gem install libv8?`

Comment: tried that, still need to install python 2.7. and even then it wont complete the setup, possible solution https://github.com/hiranpeiris/therubyracer_for_windows