# rake aborted cannot load such file --v8 windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, execjs

please help, this is my gemfile. It's an old project i created on ubuntu 12.04, now i'm trying to run it on windows 8.

source 'https://rubygems.org'

```
gem 'rails', '3.2.13'
# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'
gem 'pg'
gem 'devise', '2.2.4'
gem 'execjs', :git => 'git://github.com/kennyj/execjs.git', :branch => 'rails_issue_2880'

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  #gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby
  gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails'
  gem 'less-rails'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end
gem 'jquery-rails'
```

The command prompt:

```
C:\Users\manu\Documents\projets\rails\xibart>rake db:migrate
[WARNING] Please install gem 'therubyracer' to use Less.
rake aborted!
cannot load such file -- v8
C:/Users/manu/Documents/projets/rails/xibart/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (r
equired)>'
C:/Users/manu/Documents/projets/rails/xibart/Rakefile:5:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Comment: I installed nodejs and restarted my laptop, now it works fine

Answer (score 2):

Uncomment the ruby racer line to install it:

```
gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby
```

Comment: As far as I know, "therubyracer" gem cannot be installed on Windows (which is the OS the OP was asking about). This is not a valid solution.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6356450/therubyracer-gem-on-windows

Comment: Also not working for M1 Mac's, gonna cry..