# Removing therubyracer dependency on windows using execjs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've read an amazing solution to solve therubyracer on windows problem: [therubyracer gem on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6356450/therubyracer-gem-on-windows), but I don't exactly know how to remove the dependency of `therubyracer` from `less-rails` gem. After I bundle install a gemfile without `therubyracer`, it still display an error

`[WARNING] Please install gem 'therubyracer' to use Less...`

This is what I wrote for my gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.0.0'
gem 'rails'
gem 'execjs'

group :development do
    gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :production do
    gem 'rails_12factor'
    gem 'pg'
end

gem 'sass-rails'
gem 'coffee-rails'
gem 'uglifier'

gem 'less'
gem 'less-rails'

gem 'haml'
gem 'haml-rails'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder'
gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
gem 'designmodo-flatuipro-rails'
gem 'protected_attributes'
gem 'angularjs-rails'

group :doc do
    gem 'sdoc', require: false
end
```

Answer (score -1):

You could try [therubyracer_for_windows](https://github.com/hiranpeiris/therubyracer_for_windows), it packages the v8 dll.