# Unable to install therubyracer 0.12.0 gem on Rails 3.2 on Windows 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, therubyracer, libv8

Hi I am trying to run an existing RubyOnRails server. I used `bundle install` and got an error installing `libv8 3.16.14.3`.

this is the output for `gem install libv8 -v '3.16.14.3'

```
Fetching: libv8-3.16.14.3.gem (100%)
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing libv8:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.`

C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
creating Makefile
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3/ext/libv8/builder.rb:58:in setup_python
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3/ext/libv8/builder.rb:42:in
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3/ext/libv8/builder.rb:40:in
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3/ext/libv8/builder.rb:40:in
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3/ext/libv8/location.rb:24:in
    from extconf.rb:7:in <main>`
Gem files will remain installed in C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3 for i
Results logged to C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3/ext/libv8/gem_make.out`
```

I solved this by `gem install libv8 -v '3.16.14.3' -- --with-system-v8`

Then I get this error for `gem install therubyracer -v '0.12.0'`

```
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing therubyracer:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for main() in -lpthread... no
checking for v8.h... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/ruby
    --with-pthreadlib
    --without-pthreadlib
    --enable-debug
    --disable-debug
    --with-v8-dir
    --without-v8-dir
    --with-v8-include
    --without-v8-include=${v8-dir}/include
    --with-v8-lib
    --without-v8-lib=${v8-dir}/
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3/ext/libv8/location.rb:50:in     `configure': You have chosen to use the version of V8 found on your system    (Libv8::Location::System::NotFoundError)
and *not* the one that is bundle with the libv8 rubygem. However,
it could not be located. please make sure you have a version of
v8 that is compatible with 3.16.14.3 installed. You may
need to special --with-v8-dir options if it is in a non-standard
location

thanks,
The Mgmt

    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3/lib/libv8.rb:7:in `configure_makefile'
    from extconf.rb:32:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in     C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/therubyracer-0.12.0 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/therubyracer-    0.12.0/ext/v8/gem_make.out
```

I tried many solutions proposed on previous topics but none seems to work for my versions or I must be misunderstanding something.

Any ideas ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [therubyracer gem on windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6356450/therubyracer-gem-on-windows)

Answer (score -2):

Windows does not support `less` file.