# gem install therubyracer -v '0.12.1' fails in RubyMine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, therubyracer, libv8

When I try running the following command

```
gem install therubyracer -v '0.12.1'
```

I am getting the following error. I tried to install libv8, but was not successful then. Can someone please help me out here.

```
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing therubyracer:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    C:/software/ruby-1.9.3/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for main() in -lpthread... no
checking for v8.h... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=C:/software/ruby-1.9.3/bin/ruby
    --with-pthreadlib
    --without-pthreadlib
    --enable-debug
    --disable-debug
    --with-v8-dir
    --without-v8-dir
    --with-v8-include
    --without-v8-include=${v8-dir}/include
    --with-v8-lib
    --without-v8-lib=${v8-dir}/
C:/software/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/libv8-  
3.16.14.3/ext/libv8/location.rb:50:in `configure': You have chosen to use   
the version of V8 found on your system 
(Libv8::Location::System::NotFoundError)
and *not* the one that is bundle with the libv8 rubygem. However,
it could not be located. please make sure you have a version of
v8 that is compatible with 3.16.14.3 installed. You may
need to special --with-v8-dir options if it is in a non-standard
location

thanks,
The Mgmt

    from C:/software/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/libv8-  3.16.14.3/lib/libv8.rb:7:in `configure_makefile'
    from extconf.rb:32:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in C:/software/ruby-    1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/therubyracer-0.12.1 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/software/ruby-   1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/therubyracer-0.12.1/ext/v8/gem_make.out
```

I am new to ruby and therefore I am pretty confused what should be done here.

Answer (score 0):

You can't install `therubyracer` on Windows, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6356450/therubyracer-gem-on-windows).

Since `therubyracer` is only one of the javascript runtimes compatible with `ExecJS`, you may try anothers, say `node.js` for example.

As long as you're developing Ruby on Rails applications, sooner or later you will have to switch to Unix or Linux, so why not now?

Comment: Or set up a virtual development environment with virtual box or vmware or one of the other tools.