# First rails install: Rake aborted no javascript runtime

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

I am following a video tutorial for installing rails and after installing rails, gems, and mysql, the video walks through rake db:create as a test to ensure mysql is working correctly.

```
c:\row\dev\Hello_World>rake db:create
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
rake aborted!
Bundler::GemRequireError: There was an error while trying to load the gem 'uglifier'.
c:/row/dev/Hello_World/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
c:/row/dev/Hello_World/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
ExecJS::RuntimeUnavailable: Could not find a JavaScript runtime. See https://github.com/rails/execjs for a list of available runtimes.
c:/row/dev/Hello_World/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
c:/row/dev/Hello_World/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I'm a bit lost. Any help would be appreciated.

since it came up a couple of times in the comments, gem install therubyracer gave this:

```
ERROR:  Error installing therubyracer:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    c:/row/Ruby21/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
creating Makefile
which: no python in (.;c:\row\Ruby21\devkit\bin;c:\row\Ruby21\devkit\mingw\bin;c:\windows;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin;c:\row\Ruby21\bin)
The system cannot find the path specified.
which: no python in (.;c:\row\Ruby21\devkit\bin;c:\row\Ruby21\devkit\mingw\bin;c:\windows;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin;c:\row\Ruby21\bin)
c:/row/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.13/ext/libv8/builder.rb:81:in `setup_python!': libv8 requires python 2 to be installed in order to build, but it is currently not available (RuntimeError)
        from c:/row/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.13/ext/libv8/builder.rb:55:in `block in build_libv8!'
        from c:/row/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.13/ext/libv8/builder.rb:52:in `chdir'
        from c:/row/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.13/ext/libv8/builder.rb:52:in `build_libv8!'
        from c:/row/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.13/ext/libv8/location.rb:24:in `install!'
        from extconf.rb:7:in `<main>'

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in c:/row/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.13 for inspection.
Results logged to c:/row/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/extensions/x86-mingw32/2.1.0/libv8-3.16.14.13/gem_make.out
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try fix it:

/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/ruby_ver/gems/execjs-ver/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb

```
Node = ExternalRuntime.new(
      :name        => "Node.js (V8)",
      :command     => ["nodejs", "/usr/local/bin/node"],
      :runner_path => ExecJS.root + "/support/node_runner.js",
      :encoding    => 'UTF-8'
    )
```

Comment: Can you elaborate? I found the execjs runtimes.rb file but its not clear to me what I need to do with it.

Comment: @Mike, open it in a text editor and bring the file to a form.

Comment: Neither made any noticeable change.

Comment: Try see there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12520456/execjsruntimeerror-on-windows-trying-to-follow-rubytutorial/14118913#14118913

Comment: Ok, some progress now. The runtime error is gone but the uglifier issue is still there.

Thanks for sticking with me so far.

Answer (score 1):

Try to install [therubyracer](https://github.com/cowboyd/therubyracer) gem

Comment: gem install therubyracer gave me and error that it couldn't find the path specified and it could not find python.

Comment: add `gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby` in your Gemfile and run `bundle install`

Comment: Ok, added that to the gemfile, saved, then ran bundle install.  therubyracer does not show up on the list of gems used and it doesn't say it was installed.

Comment: I didn't pay attention that you use Windows. This answer may be useful http://stackoverflow.com/a/6359265/1998300

Comment: Looks like I don't need therubyracer gem, but its still not clear why I have an error loading uglifier on the rake db:create command.

Comment: `Uglifier` is required JS runtime. `Therubyracer` is a js interpreter into ruby, but "there is no way that I know of to currently install this gem on windows" (from the link above). And as says in the same link, on Windows you can try https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs gem instead therubyracer.

Comment: I am with you.  I removed therubyracer from my gemfile and uninstalled it.  I added execjs and ran bundle install. But I still see the same "error while trying to load uglifier" message.

Answer (score 0):

As case, You could install node.js into system.

In my AmazonWS AMI EC2 this fix it.

Comment: Node.js is installed on my system.

Comment: Such as You use Windows, may be it don't see node.js path and, possible, `restart system required`...

Comment: ...We talk about node.js but not about gem `node`. May be it is conflict node.js and node gem... You could see  nodejs.org for clear install of node.js

Answer (score 0):

Paste it into terminal

```
gem install therubyracer
```

**INSERT INTO YOUR Gemfile**

```
  gem 'uglifier', '~> 2.7', '>= 2.7.2'
```

run

```
bundle install
```

Comment: I am getting an error when I attempt to install therubyracer.  I updated the question to include the error text.

Comment: @Mike try to install nodejs