# Error installing therubyracer

Tags: ruby, rubygems, therubyracer, libv8

I am having trouble installing therubyracer on Windows Server 2012 R2.

first, i tried with `gem install therubyracer -v '0.12.3'`

which gave this output:

```
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing therubyracer:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    C:/Ruby200/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for main() in -lpthread... no
checking for v8.h... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=C:/Ruby200/bin/ruby
        --with-pthreadlib
        --without-pthreadlib
        --enable-debug
        --disable-debug
        --with-v8-dir
        --without-v8-dir
        --with-v8-include
        --without-v8-include=${v8-dir}/include
        --with-v8-lib
        --without-v8-lib=${v8-dir}/
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.17/ext/libv8/location.rb:50:in `configure': By using --with-system-v8, you have chosen to use the version  (Libv8::Location::System::NotFoundError)
of V8 found on your system and *not* the one that is bundled with
the libv8 rubygem.

However, your system version of v8 could not be located.

Please make sure your system version of v8 that is compatible
with 3.16.14.17 installed. You may need to use the
--with-v8-dir option if it is installed in a non-standard location
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.17/lib/libv8.rb:7:in `configure_makefile'
        from extconf.rb:32:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/therubyracer-0.12.3 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/therubyracer-0.12.3/ext/v8/gem_make.out
```

Also tried `gem install therubyracer -v '0.12.3' -- --with-v8-dir`

which resulted in this output:

```
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions with: '--with-v8-dir'
This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing therubyracer:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    C:/Ruby200/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb --with-v8-dir
checking for main() in -lpthread... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=C:/Ruby200/bin/ruby
        --with-pthreadlib
        --without-pthreadlib
        --enable-debug
        --disable-debug
        --with-v8-dir
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:1665:in `dir_config': undefined method `split' for true:TrueClass (NoMethodError)
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.17/ext/libv8/location.rb:49:in `configure'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.17/lib/libv8.rb:7:in `configure_makefile'
        from extconf.rb:32:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/therubyracer-0.12.3 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/therubyracer-0.12.3/ext/v8/gem_make.out
```

If you need any further information please let me know.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [therubyracer gem on windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6356450/therubyracer-gem-on-windows)

Answer (score 2):

The provided error means that you don't have g++ installed yet.

I think you need to first run this command:

```
 sudo apt-get install g++
```